# Creating views from tables that have types in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with the oe schema in oracle sql developer and I need to create a view that joins multiple tables, some of which have types or "nested" attributes.

Is there a way to put those nested attributes into a different table or eliminate them entirely? I am a relative beginner and I cant seem to find a way or similar problem online.

[image]

Here is my query and I don't even know where to start with this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is "a view with multiple tables"? Never heard the term.

Comment: a view that joins all the columns in separate tables, sorry for being unspecific

Comment: I can't view images right now. Anyway: as far as I can tell, I've never used nested tables (except for amusement) and - in my opinion - the fact that we can use them doesn't mean that we must use them. No (or just a few) advantages, many disadvantages. If possible, get rid of them by creating a simple master-detail relationship (the nested table would become a *detail* table). Then, it becomes easy to create a view you're looking for.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer then **[edit]** your question and add your query as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please.

Comment: Don't use NATURAL JOIN. It's an abomination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magic flag to exclude nested tables.

What you need to do is replace the `*` with the names of the columns you want to include. Yes that is a lot of typing but the bonus is your view has a coherent projection. At the moment your view has multiple instances of CUSTOMER_ID, ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID and CATEGORY_ID. That's illegal and confusing.

Comment: thank you! It was a long list indeed and typing it all out helped. So, instead of natural I should just use simple JOIN?

Comment: Explicit joins are best. The NATURAL JOIN syntax seems beguiling because it's less typing. But it makes a query harder to understand because now we need to look up the tables' column names to understand the join condition. Plus somebody could add a column to a table which coincides with the name of a column on the other table and change the logic of your query. And you wouldn't know until your users start complaining.